# Save TTL pulse input time while recording video from Raspicam

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I am recording video using Raspicam and saving the video buffer as well as timestamp for each frame using the following script:

```
import io
import time
import datetime as dt
from picamera import PiCamera
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue, Empty
import sys, getopt
import argparse

WIDTH  = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FRAMERATE = 30
VIDEO_STABILIZATION = True
EXPOSURE_MODE = 'night'
BRIGHTNESS = 55
CONTRAST = 50
SHARPNESS = 50
SATURATION = 30
AWB_MODE = 'off'
AWB_GAINS = 1.4

VIDEO_FILE_NAME = "cam3_output_" + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")) + ".h264"
TIMESTAMP_FILE_NAME = "cam3_timestamp_" + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")) + ".csv"
runningTimeHours, runningTimeMinutes, runningTimeSeconds = 0,0,0

class VideoOutput(Thread):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(VideoOutput, self).__init__()
        self._output = io.open(filename, 'wb', buffering=0)
        self._event = Event()
        self._queue = Queue()
        self.start()

    def write(self, buf):
        self._queue.put(buf)
        return len(buf)

    def run(self):
        while not self._event.wait(0):
            try:
                buf = self._queue.get(timeout=0.1)
            except Empty:
                pass
            else:
                self._output.write(buf)
                self._queue.task_done()

    def flush(self):
        self._queue.join()
        self._output.flush()

    def close(self):
        self._event.set()
        self.join()
        self._output.close()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._output.name


class TimestampOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, camera, video_filename, timestamp_filename):
        self.camera = camera
        self._video = VideoOutput(video_filename)
        self._timestampFile = timestamp_filename
        self._timestamps = []

    def write(self, buf):
        if self.camera.frame.complete and self.camera.frame.timestamp is not None:
            self._timestamps.append((
                self.camera.frame.timestamp,
                self.camera.dateTime,
                self.camera.clockRealTime
                ))
        return self._video.write(buf)

    def flush(self):
        with io.open(self._timestampFile, 'w') as f:
            f.write('GPU Times, time.time(), clock_realtime\n')
            for entry in self._timestamps:
                f.write('%d,%f,%f\n' % entry)

    def close(self):
        self._video.close()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-hr", "--hours", type=int, help="number of hours to record")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--minutes", type=int, help="number of minutes to record")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--seconds", type=int, help="number of seconds to record")
args = parser.parse_args()


runningTimeHours = float(args.hours)
runningTimeMinutes = float(args.minutes)
runningTimeSeconds = float(args.seconds)

totalRunningTime = runningTimeHours*60*60 + runningTimeMinutes*60 + runningTimeSeconds

with PiCamera(resolution=(WIDTH, HEIGHT), framerate=FRAMERATE) as camera:
    camera.brightness = BRIGHTNESS
    camera.contrast = CONTRAST
    camera.sharpness = SHARPNESS
    camera.video_stabilization = VIDEO_STABILIZATION
    camera.hflip = False
    camera.vflip = False

    #warm-up time to camera to set its initial settings
    time.sleep(2)

    camera.exposure_mode = EXPOSURE_MODE
    camera.awb_mode = AWB_MODE
    camera.awb_gains = AWB_GAINS

    #time to let camera change parameters according to exposure and AWB
    time.sleep(2)

    #switch off the exposure since the camera has been set now 
    camera.exposure_mode = 'off'

    output = TimestampOutput(camera, VIDEO_FILE_NAME, TIMESTAMP_FILE_NAME)
    try:
        camera.start_preview()
        # Construct an instance of our custom output splitter with a filename  and a connected socket
        print('Starting Recording')
        camera.start_recording(output, format='h264')
        print('Started Recording')
        camera.wait_recording(totalRunningTime)
        camera.stop_recording()
        camera.stop_preview()
        print('Recording Stopped')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Closing Output File')
        sys.exit(2)
    finally:
        output.close()
        print('Output File Closed')
```

Simultaneously while this recording is going on, I am sending TTL pulse to GPIO pin 4. I now want to add a code block to the above script so that for each TTL HIGH input received I can save the corresponding time value in a file.

Something like this without camera running script involved:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pinTTL = 4

GPIO.setup(pinTTL, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    count = 0
    inputState = GPIO.input(pinTTL)
    if inputState == True:
        print 'HIGH', time.time()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

The above script for pin state set to HIGH saves the time.time() value.

Basically I want to integrate the 2 scripts mentioned. I tried creating another thread to save time.time() values according to TTL input in the same way I am saving video buffer was getting error cause of that.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use interrupts with a GPIO.add_event_detect() callback on a rising edge?

Comment: Does this event detect function only logs time points where the change happened from HIGH to LOW or LOW to HIGH?
How to create a separate thread in the script which keeps on saving the time.time() for respective input state

Comment: A rising edge would be LOW to HIGH and a falling edge is HIGH to LOW. You can define an event to trigger on either or both. For the TTL pulse I'd do it on the rising edge (only), but YMMV.  RPi.GPIO runs the callback functions in a separate thread, so you don't need to create a thread for it. Define a global timestamp variable that is updated by the  the callback, that way you will not need to bother with the timestamp file, unless you need it for some other purpose. If you do need it, write to the file in your main loop, don't write in one thread (the callback) and read in another...

Comment: I used the code in this link http://pastebin.com/0x2KVbdh to combine both the things but TTL are not getting logged on raspberry pi after 20mins run somehow

Comment: Sounds like a problem with memory or disk, have you checked this? Is there no exceptions or errors indicated? Have you tried to add prints to try to find where it stops? Or does your TTL pulse stop, somehow?

Comment: No I have more than enough memory. There was no exception or error indicated. I am testing it more to find out source of error.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is TTL pulse logs an event when there is no change in input state. For example, it logs LOW LOW LOW continuously in less than 1 second (pulse width used: 1second). So theoretically, only one event should be logged in ~1seconds

Comment: Add a debounce by passing a bouncetime to the add_event_detect?

Comment: Thanks the bouncetime really helped. 
I am going to close this question as the pastebin link seems to be working fine on it's now. My further tests, it has stopped crashing somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to the final script: http://pastebin.com/0x2KVbdh and the cost is pasted below.

As mentioned by jogco using event_detect_callback, which creates thread for handling HIGH to LOW and LOW to HIGH edges, I was able to log timestamps values at each of these edges.

```
import io
import time
import datetime as dt
from picamera import PiCamera
from threading import Thread, Event
from queue import Queue, Empty
import sys, getopt
import argparse
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#camera parameter setting
WIDTH  = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FRAMERATE = 30
VIDEO_STABILIZATION = True
EXPOSURE_MODE = 'night'
BRIGHTNESS = 55
CONTRAST = 50
SHARPNESS = 50
SATURATION = 30
AWB_MODE = 'off'
AWB_GAINS = 1.4

#video, timestamps and ttl file name
VIDEO_FILE_NAME = "cam4_output_" + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")) + ".h264"
TIMESTAMP_FILE_NAME = "cam4_timestamp_" + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")) + ".csv"
TTL_FILE_NAME = "cam4_ttl_" + str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")) + ".csv"

#running time variable intialization
runningTimeHours, runningTimeMinutes, runningTimeSeconds = 0,0,0

#set raspberry pi board layout to BCM
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#pin number to receive TTL input
pinTTL = 4
#set the pin as input pin
GPIO.setup(pinTTL, GPIO.IN)
#add event detection script to GPIO pin
GPIO.add_event_detect(pinTTL, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=900)

#video output thread to save video file
class VideoOutput(Thread):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(VideoOutput, self).__init__()
        self._output = io.open(filename, 'wb', buffering=0)
        self._event = Event()
        self._queue = Queue()
        self.start()

    def write(self, buf):
        self._queue.put(buf)
        return len(buf)

    def run(self):
        while not self._event.wait(0):
            try:
                buf = self._queue.get(timeout=0.1)
            except Empty:
                pass
            else:
                self._output.write(buf)
                self._queue.task_done()

    def flush(self):
        self._queue.join()
        self._output.flush()

    def close(self):
        self._event.set()
        self.join()
        self._output.close()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._output.name

#timestamp output object to save timestamps according to pi and TTL inputs received and write to file
class TimestampOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, camera, video_filename, timestamp_filename, ttl_filename):
        self.camera = camera
        self._video = VideoOutput(video_filename)
        self._timestampFile = timestamp_filename
        self._ttlFile = ttl_filename
        self._timestamps = []
        self._ttlTimestamps = []

    def ttlTimestampsWrite(self, input_pin):
        try:
            inputState = GPIO.input(input_pin)
            self._ttlTimestamps.append((inputState, self.camera.frame.timestamp, self.camera.dateTime, self.camera.clockRealTime))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            pass

    def write(self, buf):
        if self.camera.frame.complete and self.camera.frame.timestamp is not None:
            self._timestamps.append((
                self.camera.frame.timestamp,
                self.camera.dateTime,
                self.camera.clockRealTime
                ))
        return self._video.write(buf)

    def flush(self):
        with io.open(self._timestampFile, 'w') as f:
            f.write('GPU Times, time.time(), clock_realtime\n')
            for entry in self._timestamps:
                f.write('%d,%f,%f\n' % entry)
        with io.open(self._ttlFile, 'w') as f:
            f.write('Input State, GPU Times, time.time(), clock_realtime\n')
            for entry in self._ttlTimestamps:
                f.write('%f,%f,%f,%f\n' % entry)

    def close(self):
        self._video.close()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-hr", "--hours", type=int, help="number of hours to record")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--minutes", type=int, help="number of minutes to record")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--seconds", type=int, help="number of seconds to record")
args = parser.parse_args()

runningTimeHours = float(args.hours)
runningTimeMinutes = float(args.minutes)
runningTimeSeconds = float(args.seconds)

totalRunningTime = runningTimeHours*60*60 + runningTimeMinutes*60 + runningTimeSeconds

with PiCamera(resolution=(WIDTH, HEIGHT), framerate=FRAMERATE) as camera:
    camera.brightness = BRIGHTNESS
    camera.contrast = CONTRAST
    camera.sharpness = SHARPNESS
    camera.video_stabilization = VIDEO_STABILIZATION
    camera.hflip = False
    camera.vflip = False

    #warm-up time to camera to set its initial settings
    time.sleep(2)

    camera.exposure_mode = EXPOSURE_MODE
    camera.awb_mode = AWB_MODE
    camera.awb_gains = AWB_GAINS

    #time to let camera change parameters according to exposure and AWB
    time.sleep(2)

    #switch off the exposure since the camera has been set now
    camera.exposure_mode = 'off'

    output = TimestampOutput(camera, VIDEO_FILE_NAME, TIMESTAMP_FILE_NAME, TTL_FILE_NAME)
    GPIO.add_event_callback(pinTTL, output.ttlTimestampsWrite)
    try:
        camera.start_preview()
        # Construct an instance of our custom output splitter with a filename  and a connected socket
        print('Starting Recording')
        camera.start_recording(output, format='h264')
        print('Started Recording')
        camera.wait_recording(totalRunningTime)
        camera.stop_recording()
        camera.stop_preview()
        print('Recording Stopped')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Closing Output File')
        sys.exit(2)
    except:
        output.close()
        print('exception! output file closed')
    finally:
        output.close()
        print('Output File Closed')
```